# Unable to start mongod on Ubuntu 16.04 - "Unable to connect to Upstart"

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

[image: screenshot showing systemctl status]

This is the status of mongod service

```
Unable to connect to upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart:
 Connection refused
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: @VladSpirin please make images hyperlinks, especially when they are screenshots with tiny text (see the edit for the syntax) and Ankit Singh please copy and paste text from your terminal and format as code with the `{}` button rather than showing a screenshot, unless the screenshot shows something that text cannot - text is searchable, copyable and more accessible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start MongoDB with systemctl in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Check the status.

```
mongo
```

It should appear in the mongo shell.

Comment: Alternatively depending on how you installed mongodb the command `sudo systemctl status mongod` will check that the service has started properly.